# How to temporarily prevent a web page in Chrome to intercept a paste operation?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, copy-paste

I am using a password manager to generate safe, long, unique passwords. Because those passwords tend to be 20-characters long they are a pain to type, but they are not even intended to be typed, merely cut and paste.

Now, some webapps (e.g. PayPal when creating a new user) actively intercept *paste* operation from the JS in the page in order to *prevent me* from actually pasting my nicely generated password.

How can I temporarily prevent the JS in Chrome to intercept the *paste* operation, making it appears as if I had entered sequentially, albeit very fast, the content of buffer?

Comment: Use the Chrome extension [Don't Fuck With Paste](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-fuck-with-paste/nkgllhigpcljnhoakjkgaieabnkmgdkb?hl=en])